# jquery chosen mark new elements

Tags: jquery, addclass, jquery-chosen

I am using the [jQuery plugin chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in a form. I want to mark new elements, in order to add them to the database on form submit.

I am trying:

```
$('#id_tags').chosen({
    display_selected_options: false,
    create_option: function(term) {
        var chosen = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/aj/tag/neu/',
            data: {
                tag_name: term
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            chosen.append_option({
              value: data.tag_id,
              text: data.tag_name
            });
            $('li.search-choice:contains(' + data.tag_name +')').addClass("new");
        });
    }, ...
}
```

It works with every new**est** element, i.e. the most recently added element A gets the "new" class added, however when another element B is added the "new"-class is removed from A and only present on B.

```
<ul class="chosen-choices">
  <li class="search-choice"><span>A</span><a data-option-array-index="1" class="search-choice-close"></a></li>
  <li class="search-choice new"><span>B</span><a data-option-array-index="174" class="search-choice-close"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Why is that? Or how can i achive a persistent marker to all added elements?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the class to the real <option> element, then do a

```
$('#myRealSelect').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

and your class will persist on your chosen list.